# Automatic Reference Counting still produces memory leaks?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have app for editing images. I decided to enable ARC to forget memory managment. But I guess it was not a good idea. My app's image opening works like that:

```
                              NSBitmapImageRep -> CIImage -> CIFilter -> NSBitmapImageRep -> CGImage -> other OpenGL texture -> 
                   CGImage ->                                                                                                   draw everything to seperate Framebuffers and then these framebuffers to main framebuffer and then to screen
                              OpenGL texture
File -> NSImage ->
                   CIImage -> CIFilters -> second CIImage -> NSBitmapImageRep -> CIImage on other class
                           -> NSBitmapImageRep -> CIImage on other class
```

When I launch my app I have:

[image]

And after opening 5.3MB size image (3200x2000) I have:

[image]

And it never goes down. Maybe I haven't got enough information about using ARC? But as I understood it manages almost everything related to memory management, doesn't it?

---

Leak detector output:

Just after running my app:

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame

__NSMallocBlock__   507 < multiple >    31.69 KB         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc1c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc220 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc270 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc2b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc320 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc390 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc3e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc420 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc460 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc4a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc4e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc540 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc580 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc5c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc620 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc660 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc6d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc740 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc780 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc7c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc800 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc840 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc8b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc8f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc930 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc970 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc9b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadc9f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadca30 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcaa0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcae0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcb20 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcb90 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcbd0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcc10 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcc50 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcc90 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcce0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcd40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcd80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcdc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadce00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadce40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcea0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcee0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcf50 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcfb0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadcff0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd030 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd070 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd0b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd0f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd130 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd170 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd1c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd200 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd240 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd280 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd2c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd300 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd360 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd3a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd3e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd420 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd460 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd4a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd510 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd550 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd590 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd5f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd630 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd670 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd6b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd6f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd750 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd790 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd800 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd840 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd880 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd8c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd900 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd940 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd980 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadd9c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadda00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadda40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadda80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddac0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddb00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddb40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddb80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddbc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddc00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddc40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddc90 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddcd0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddd10 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddd50 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddd90 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadddd0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadde20 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadde60 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddea0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddf10 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddf50 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddf90 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaddfd0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade010 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade050 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade090 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade0e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade120 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade160 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade1a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade200 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade240 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade280 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade2d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade310 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade350 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade390 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade3d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade410 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade470 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade4b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade4f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade530 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade5a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade5f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade630 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade670 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade6b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade6f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade750 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade7a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade7e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade820 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade880 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade8c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade900 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade940 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade980 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eade9c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadea00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadea70 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadeab0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadeaf0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadeb30 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadeb70 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadebb0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadebf0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadec30 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadec70 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadecc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaded00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaded40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eaded80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadedc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadee00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadee40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadee80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadeec0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadef00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadef40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadef80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadefc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf000 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf040 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf0b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf0f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf130 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf170 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf1b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf1f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf230 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf270 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf2c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf300 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf340 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf380 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf3c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf430 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf4a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf4e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf520 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf560 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf5a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10eadf5e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101379560 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013795a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101379970 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101379ce0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10137b690 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10137b980 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10137b9c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10137ba30 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10137baa0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10137bcf0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10137bfc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10137eaf0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10137eb30 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10137eb90 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x10137ebd0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381790 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013817d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381810 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381850 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381890 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013818d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381910 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381950 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381990 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013819d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381a40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381a80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381ac0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381b00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381b40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381b80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381bc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381c00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381c40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381c80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381cc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381d00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381d40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381d80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381dc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381e10 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381e50 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381e90 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381ed0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381f40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381f90 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101381fd0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382010 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382050 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382090 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013820d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382110 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382150 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382190 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013821d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382220 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382260 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013822a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013822e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382320 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382360 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013823c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382400 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382440 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382480 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013824f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382530 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382570 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013825b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013825f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382630 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382670 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013826b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013826f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382730 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382770 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013827c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382800 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382840 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382880 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013828c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382900 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382940 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382980 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013829c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382a20 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382a60 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382ab0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382af0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382b50 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382b90 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382bd0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382c10 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382c70 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382ce0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382d20 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382d60 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382da0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382e10 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382e50 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382e90 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382ed0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382f10 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382f50 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382f90 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101382fd0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383010 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383050 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383090 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013830d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383110 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383150 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383190 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013831d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383210 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383250 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383290 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013832d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383320 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383360 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013833a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383400 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383480 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013834c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383500 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383540 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383580 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013835c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383600 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383640 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383680 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013836c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383700 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383740 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013837b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013837f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383830 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383870 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013838b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013838f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383930 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383970 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013839b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013839f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383a30 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383a70 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383ab0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383af0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383b40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383b80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383bc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383c00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383c40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383c80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383cc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383d00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383d40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383d80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383dc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383e00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383e70 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383eb0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383f10 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383f50 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383f90 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101383fd0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384010 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384050 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384090 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013840e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384120 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384160 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013841a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013841e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384220 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384260 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013842a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013842e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384320 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384360 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013843a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013843e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384420 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384480 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013844c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384500 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384540 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384580 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013845d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384610 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384650 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384690 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013846d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384720 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384760 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013847a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013847e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384830 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384890 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013848d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384930 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384980 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013849c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384a00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384a70 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384ab0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384af0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384b30 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384b70 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384bb0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384bf0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384c30 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384c70 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384cc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384d00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384d40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384d80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384df0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384e30 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384e70 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384eb0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384ef0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384f30 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384f80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101384fc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385000 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385050 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385090 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013850f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385130 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385190 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013851d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385210 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385250 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385290 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013852d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385310 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385370 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013853c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385400 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385440 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385480 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013854d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385510 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385550 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385590 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013855d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385610 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385660 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013856a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013856e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385730 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385770 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013857b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013857f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385830 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385870 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013858b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013858f0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013859a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1013859e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x101385a20 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100204290 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002042e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100204320 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002043c0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100206200 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002062a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002062e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100206350 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002063d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002064e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002065d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100206670 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002066b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100206b60 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100206ba0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100206c10 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100206db0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100206ec0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100206ff0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002070d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100207360 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002073a0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100207990 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002079e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100207ba0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100207be0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100207d40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100207f10 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100207f50 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100208160 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100208210 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002087e0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100208b70 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x100209150 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002091b0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002ae910 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002ae950 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002ae990 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002ae9d0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aea40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aea80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aeac0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aeb00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aeb40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aeb80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aebc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aec00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aec40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aec80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aecc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aed00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aed40 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aed80 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aedc0 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aee00 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002aee70 64 Bytes         
     __NSMallocBlock__  1   0x1002af020 64 Bytes

Malloc 548.00 KB        1   0x106983000 548.00 KB
```

And while/after opening image no leaks are being detected.

Comment: tip: if you run the program with the "Leaks" Instrument, it will record the backtraces for all of those allocations.

Answer (score 4):

> Maybe I haven't got enough information about using ARC? But as I understood it manages almost everything related to memory management, doesn't it?

Hardly -- It only manages ObjC Objects.

For example: If you `malloc`, `new`, use Opaque C types (e.g. CFString, CGColor), you will still need to manage these allocations or their reference counts explicitly.

Comment: and yes, this supplements other answers (+1)

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two possibilities that apply even with ARC:

1. Some APIs, such as [`[UIImage imageNamed:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), will cache objects they create.
2. ARC, being a reference-counting mechanism, is susceptible to reference cycles. If an object points (directly or indirectly) to itself, it — and every other object it points to — will never be freed.

Have you run your app through the leak detector?

Comment: Added leak detector output to question. I'm not using `imageNamed` anywhere, I use `initWithContentsOfFile`. And what does `If an object points to itself` means? `object = object;`?

Comment: @JuliusPetraška: It doesn't look like memory leaks are the issue here. There isn't anywhere enough to explain the memory consumption you're seeing. An object may contain a pointer to a delegate. If it acts as its own delegate (`self.delegate = self`) it will leak. This can happen in more subtle ways, such as when two objects point to each other.

Comment: @MarceloCantos usually a delegate has a weak reference, so self.delegate = self shouldn't cause a leak. Or there is something I'm missing?

Comment: As I noticed, allocations could be a problem. After opening image I have `675.28 MB` of allocations

Comment: @JuliusPetraška have you tried to simulate a memory warning to be sure it's not some kind of cache? How was the memory consumption without ARC?

Comment: No, I haven't. Without ARC it was something like ~+50 mb after opening an image. But after enabling ARC I added some code, and I haven't looked to memory consumption just after enabling it.